# Angular - Login Page Redirects to Home Page Without Clicking on Submit

Tags: angular

I am developing a web application using Angular-7. I have the Login, Home and Landing Pages:

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../shared/services/api.service';
import { TokenService } from '../../../shared/services/token.service';
import { Router, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../../shared/services/auth.service';
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';

declare var $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public loggedIn: boolean;

  public form = {
    email : null,
    password : null,
    remember_me : false
  };

  student = null;
  name = null;
  students = null;

  public error = null;

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService,
    private token: TokenService,
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private notify: SnotifyService,
    private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    if(this.token.loggedIn) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    }

    document.body.className = 'hold-transition login-page';
    $(() => {
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
        increaseArea: '20%' /* optional */
      });
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.notify.info('Wait...', {timeout: 0});
    this.spinnerService.show();
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
    return this.api.post('login', this.form, headers).subscribe(
      data => this.tokenHandler(data),
      error => this.errorHandler(error.error)
    );
  }

  errorHandler(error){
    this.spinnerService.hide();
    this.notify.clear();
    console.log(error);
    if(error.errors && error.errors.email){
      this.error = error.errors.email;
    }
    else if(error.message=='Unauthorized'){
      this.error = null;
      this.notify.error('Invalid Login Details or email not confirmed', {timeout: 0})
    } else {
      this.error = null;
      this.notify.error(error.message, {timeout:0})
    }
  }

  tokenHandler(data){
    this.notify.clear();
    console.log(data);
    this.token.setRoles(data.user.roles);
    this.token.set(data.token_type + " " + data.access_token, data);
    this.auth.changeAuthStatus(true);
    this.loggedIn = true;
    this.notify.info('Login Succesfully', {timeout: 2000});
    this.wait(999);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    window.location.reload();
  }

  private wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
  }

}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import {dashboard2} from 'src/assets/dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js';
import { RolesCheckService } from 'src/app/shared/services/roles-check.service';

declare var $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  isAdmin = false;
  isStaff = false;
  isManager = false;

  constructor(private role: RolesCheckService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

    document.body.className = 'skin-blue sidebar-mini';

    if(localStorage.getItem('token') !=null && localStorage.getItem('role')==null) {
      this.wait(1100);
    }
    this.isAdmin = this.role.isAdmin || this.role.isSuperAdmin;
    this.isStaff = this.role.isStaff;
    this.isManager = this.role.isManager;
  }

  private wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    document.body.className = '';
  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/landing', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent },

  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'client-quote-landing',
    component: ClientQuotesLandingComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate : [AfterloginService]
  },

];
```

The Landing Page is the default page. After this the Login Page, and then the Home Page

landing-component.html

```
 <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a routerLink="/login"><i class="fa fa-unlock margin-right-10px"></i> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I expect that when I click on Login in Landing Page as shown above. But rather, it redirects me to Home Page.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you put `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/landing', pathMatch: 'full' }` at the bottom of your routes array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are logged in

login.component.ts
ngOnInit() {

```
if(this.token.loggedIn) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}
```

try by removing this check, if it works then check your token.

Comment: 1.  When I removed if(this.token.loggedIn) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}  Then login, it redirects me back to the Login Page.   2. What do you mean that I should check my token?

Comment: can you show AfterLoginService file, i think thisguard is stoping you from accessing /home

Comment: Thanks so much, problem solved. After removing if(this.token.loggedIn) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}.  Then I also removed 
window.location.reload();   from login component.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the order of the routes.

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first. - [Taken from](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Try the following instead:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent },

    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'client-quote-landing',
      component: ClientQuotesLandingComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent,
      canActivate : [AfterloginService]
    },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/landing', pathMatch: 'full' }
 ];
```

Comment: I did the rearrangement, but the problem is still there